# SASS: 'Undefined variable' when using @extend

Tags: css, sass

I want to use some generic styling for my android and ios stylesheets. So I have placed the generic styles inside one file.

_base.scss

```
%base {
    color: $baseColor;
}
```

Now I want to use this for both stylesheets:

main-ios.scss:

```
@import 'base';

$baseColor: #fff;
main {
    @extend %base;
}
```

main-android.scss:

```
@import 'base';

$baseColor: #000;
main {
    @extend %base;
}
```

I expect this to compile to (for android):

```
main {
    color: #000;
}
```

but, instead I get

```
Syntax error: Undefined variable: "$baseColor".
```

Is there anyway I this can be fixed ?

UPDATE:

I figured it out, first define variables inside the main file than the import!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried defining your variable before the import declaration?

```
$baseColor: #000;

@import 'base';

main {
    @extend %base;
}
```